# ReactDOM.render() is showing nothing

Tags: reactjs

i am a beginner learning react but i get trouble from my first react code, the ReactDOM.render() is showing anything. what is the problem?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>react</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../REACT/style.css">
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="../REACT/app.js" type="text/babel">
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, everyone!</h1>, document.getElementById("root"))

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

i expect to see hello everyone! but it shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from the script tag:

```
src="../REACT/app.js"
```